# Is there a way to get the max number of versions kept for documents in microsoft-graph?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Is there a way in the api-graph (v1 or beta) to get the max number of major version kept for a document in onedrive or sharepoint.

The number I'm searching for correspond from what we should be able to find from the ui at : 
List setting > versioning setting > "Keep the following number of major versions"

[number of major versions kept in sharepoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYgdH.png)

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-long-are-versions-kept-in-the-version-history/cf7d953f-f522-45bf-97a9-35286a79b94e

Any way to get this number calling the graph api ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the [following Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-versions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) call and see if it helps.

GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/versions

Comment: Hi Remi, if this answer answers your question can you please mark it as answered so that it may be helpful to others for reference in future.